# ПК не видит другой ПК в сети

Tags: windows, настройка, lan

Есть сеть. 13 Компов,
С одного компа (x10) не могу зайти на комп (x0). На все остальные компы видят друг друга. Причем пинги идут как x10 на x0, так и наоборот.

ОС на x0 стоит windows 8.1, на остальных 7.
Настройки сети на x0:
  IP: 192.168.137.1/24  Dns: 192.168.137.253  Gateway: 192.168.137.253

На всех остальных: 
   IP: 192.168.137.[101 - 112]/24  DNS && Gateway такой же как на win8

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: С x0 я могу зайти в общие папки на x10. Наоборот не могу. Пинги в обе стороны проходят. В чем может быть проблема?  Пробовал очистить кэш DNS ( ipconfig /flushdns )- не помогло

Comment: Коротко: net view с x10 не видит x0

Comment: Домен или рабгруппа? Адреса статика или DHCP?

Comment: Выключите в свойствах интерфейса IPv6

Comment: Адреса статика, Домена нет, везде стоит рабочая группа с именем "WORKGROUP"

Answer (score 0):

Проблему нашел, оказывается кто-то в настройках адаптера отключил Службу доступа к файлам и принтерам.